# Hurewicz isomorphism in equivariant stable homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $X$ be a $G$-CW-complex. Denote by $\pi_{\ast}^G(X)$ the $G$-equivariant stable homotopy groups of $G$ and by $\mathrm{H}_{\ast}^G(X,A(-))$ the Bredon homology of $G$ with coefficients in the Burnside ring.

My question is:

1) If $\pi_{\ast}^G(X)$ is zero for all $\ast$, can one conclude that  $\mathrm{H}_{\ast}^G(X,A(-))$ is zero for all $\ast$?

2) More generally, is there is a Hurewicz map
$$\pi_{\ast}^G(X) \rightarrow \mathrm{H}_{\ast}^G(X,A(-)) $$
and a criteria that says when this map is an isomorphism?

Thanks.